# Why does the query that uses Remote View take too long to execute?

Tags: oracle, optimization, plsql

I have a simple query (Oracle 19)

```sql
SELECT T.ID, T.PID, R.MESS, R.REMOTE_USR, R.COMMENT 
FROM TABLE1 T
JOIN SOME_VIEW@REMOTE R ON R.ID = T.PID
WHERE T.ID = 'some ID'
```

execution  plan

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 1 | 280 | 23 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 | HASH JOIN |  | 1 | 280 | 23 | 00:00:01 |
| 2 | TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TABLE1 | 1 | 57 | 1 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 | INDEX UNIQUE SCAN | PK_TABLE1_ID | 1 |  | 0 | 00:00:01 |
| 4 | REMOTE | SOME_VIEW | 2 | 446 | 22 | 00:00:01 |

It runs too long. TABLE1 has less than 100 rows and field ID is the primary key.

But the query

```sql
SELECT T.ID, T.PID, R.MESS, R.REMOTE_USR, R.COMMENT 
FROM TABLE1 T
JOIN SOME_VIEW@REMOTE R ON R.ID = T.PID
WHERE R.ID = 'some PID'
```

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 1 | 274 | 25 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 | HASH JOIN |  | 1 | 274 | 25 | 00:00:01 |
| 2 | REMOTE | SOME_VIEW | 1 | 223 | 22 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 | TABLE ACCESS FULL | TABLE1 | 1 | 51 | 3 | 00:00:01 |

works perfectly.
I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local database is choosing to use a hash join on the local and remote tables. Since your first query doesn't apply any predicate to the remote table, it has to process 100% of it's data and return it over the network to the local database. Only then does the hash join take place and due to the predicate filter on the local table you get filtered down to the results you want.

The second query is applying a predicate to the remote table. That is getting predicate pushed into the view and allowing that view to much more efficiently get just the data you want and return only what's of interest.

If you are always going to be working with a single row from `TABLE1`, then you may want to force a nested loops:

```
SELECT /*+ LEADING(t) USE_NL(R) */ T.ID, T.PID, R.MESS, R.REMOTE_USR, R.COMMENT 
FROM TABLE1 T
JOIN SOME_VIEW@REMOTE R ON R.ID = T.PID
WHERE T.ID = 'some ID'
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first query, you are returning one row from the local table and comparing it to the entire remote view. You have no visibility into how that view is constructed, the workload or resources of the remote database, or how much data is being processed there with all of the latency that comes with pushing that over the network.

In your second query, you are only returning a single row from the remote view, which is apparently processed very quickly, and comparing that to the local table, which is also accessed quickly. I can't say for sure since you haven't included any more details, but I suspect that the remote view doesn't scale well when dealing with multiple rows of data; perhaps it has a lot of embedded inline SQL functions?